# $near in mongo with array of locations in each document

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm looking to get a proximity of users within an area by using the $near operator in mongodb and I'm unsure of the correct way to do so.

In my route I have a JavaScript model (mongoose) looking up users that are local to the proximity:

```
collection.find({
  $elemMatch: {
    locations: {
      $near: coords,
      $maxDistance: maxDistance
    }
  }
})
```

The schema design:

```
first_name: String,
  last_name: String,
  locations: [
    {
      suburb: String,
      state: String,
      postcode: String,
      longitude: Number,
      latitude: Number
    }
  ]
```

Each user has many locations and each has latitude and longitude. I tried $elemMatch with no success and I'm not sure if I need to aggregate or use a different operator.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the GeoJSON Point format for storing the coordinates, and then use the mongodb 2dsphere index.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/2dsphere/

You will then be able to use geoNear with maxDistance and minDistance. It is very useful.

So my suggestion is that you modify your schema to:

```
first_name: String,
  last_name: String,
  locations: [
    {
      suburb: String,
      state: String,
      postcode: String,
      geometry: {
         type: "Point",
         coordinates: [ Number, Number ]
      }
    }
  ]
```

(geometry being GeoJSON Point format)

Comment: Can u please provide the query ?

Comment: I don't do mongoose, but in plain mongodb js code it looks like this:

Comment: with a simple aggregation pipeline:     `var queryPoint={type:"Point",coordinates:[13.21,55.22]}; var aggregationpipeline=[{$geoNear: {"near": queryPoint,"query":{'properties.flowertype':{$exists: false}}}}];var mycursor = collection.aggregate(aggregationpipeline);`